# Can Airflow running in a Docker container access a local file?

Tags: docker, airflow

I am a newbie as far as both Airflow and Docker are concerned; to make things more complicated, I use Astronomer, and to make things worse, I run Airflow on Windows. (Not on a Unix subsystem - could not install Docker on Ubuntu 20.4). "astro dev start" breaks with an error, but in Docker Desktop I see, and can start, 3 Airflow-related containers. They see my DAGs just fine, but my DAGs don't see the local file system. Is thus unavoidable with the Airflow + Docker combo? (Seems like a big handicap; one can only use a file in the cloud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can declare a volume at image runtime in Docker using the `-v` switch with your `docker run` command to mount a local folder on your host to a mount point in your container, and you can access that point from inside the container.
If you go on to use `docker-compose up` to orchestrate your containers, you can [specify volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) in the `docker-compose.yml` file for your containers which configures the volumes for the containers that run.

In your case, the Astronomer docs [here](https://www.astronomer.io/docs/cloud/stable/develop/customize-image#docker-compose-override) suggest it is possible to create a custom directive in the Astronomer `docker-compose.override.yml` file to mount the volumes in the Airflow containers created as part of your `astro` commands for your stack which should then be visible from your DAGs.